# Div showing on one page and not showing on another page

Tags: html, css, google-chrome-devtools

I am facing a weird problem where a div (This div is generated when user clicks on Combobox  to show options) is visible on one page (call it page A) and it is not visible on another page (page B). In Chrome Developer Tools, I could see it get generated at both places. The one difference that is there is on page B, the ComboBox is inside a modal whereas on page A the combobox is on the main page itself. My guess is that some css class of modal might be causing the issue, but my question is around how do I find the culprit class or difference. Is there a way in Chrome or Firefox developer tools to find the difference between the visible and invisible divs. Can the stackoverflow front end ninjas suggest me an approach here

Comment: yeah it can be due to modal. Try showing your modal which consist your div. May be your div is created but modal is hidden that's why you can't see your div. Post your code  for more understanding.

Comment: Have you compared CSS of the two in `Computed` sub-panel?